# Spring Boot REST Service is not displaying the @ResponseStatus exception reason in JSON output

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created an exception Annotated with `@ResponseStatus` allowing to throw the exception and receive the reason from the JSON content in the frontend.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = BAD_REQUEST,  reason='exception.user.exists')
class UserAlreadyExists extends RuntimeException{
}
```

When I try to resolving the Message by key in a service is working I get the localized message.

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource

    private void verifyIsNewUser(User user) {
    if (userRepository.countByEmail(user.email)) {
        def reason = this.messageSource.getMessage("exception.user.exists", null, "just a message", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()); 
        println reason // User already registered
        throw new UserAlreadyExists()
    }
}
```

### Question 1

Now if I Debug the [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.java#L84) I see that MessageSource is **null** which is strange. As `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` is implementing the interface `MessageSourceAware` it should have a messageSource injected. Why isn't it?

### Question 2

If I ignore the fact that I have no custom message and look at the JSON output that is reaching the frontend I am faced with the following result:

```
{"timestamp":1414403066197,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"io.test.UserAlreadyExists","message":null,"path":"/register/"}
```

There is **nothing about a reason** text field that I expected to see in the JSON response. Something like `{...,"reason":"exception.user.exists","message":null, ....}`.

Why doesn't the JSON response contain the reason (key)? When looking at the code of [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.java#L84) if no message by key is retrieved then just the key/message is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: a bug in Spring IMO. The `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver` is not a `@Bean` so it won't be injected with a `MessageSource`.

Answer 2: feature request for Spring Boot. You are seeing the default /error output from Boot, which is looking in the `Exception` for a message, not the `HttpServletResponse` "reason" code (I assume that is available through an API). Here's a link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1762.

Comment: Regarding 1: When it is not a Bean why is it using MessageSource or is it instantiated with new? Because there seems to be an instance of it in the system as I am able to debug some instance But I don't know if it is a bean or not.

Comment: It's instantiated with "new" in the `@MVC` configuration.